# Как удалить пробелы из объекта?

Tags: c#, replace

Необходимо удалить пробелы из объекта, через Trim() и Replace() - не получается. Пишет, что ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. К чему слова, вот код:

```
public class Analysis
{
    public string TestMethodCode { get; set; }
    public string TestGroupCode { get; set; }
}

class SaveInDb
{
public void inMysql(string xmlFile)
{
        HL7 hl7 = new HL7();
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

        var analysis =
            xdoc
            .Root
            .Descendants("Analysis");

        List<Analysis> result = new List<Analysis>();

        foreach (var a in analysis)
        {
            Analysis temp = new Analysis();
            temp.AnaComment =(string)a.Element("AnaComment")?.Attribute("Text");
            temp.Culture =
                    a.Elements("Culture")
                     ?.Select(x =>
                        new Culture
                        {
                            Finding = (string)x.Attribute("Finding"),
                            Growth = (string)x.Attribute("Growth"),
                            Resistances =
                                x.Elements("Resistence")
                                  .Select(r => new Resistance
                                  {
                                      Antibiotics = (string)r.Attribute("Antibiotics"),
                                      SIR = (string)r.Attribute("SIR")
                                  }).ToList()

                        }).ToList();

            HL7 ob = new HL7();

            //Атрибуты TestMethodCode и TestGroupCode могут содержать пробелы
            //Необходимо чтобы присваивались значения уже без пробелов
            temp.TestMethodCode = (string)a.Attribute("TestMethodCode"); 
            temp.TestGroupCode = (string)a.Attribute("TestGroupCode");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Не компилируется. В классе `Analysis` нет свойств `AnaComment` и `Culture`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я просто не добавил их. Там все есть, и все хорошо компилируется) Вопрос в том, как удалить пробелы в коде (под комментариями)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class Analysis
{
  private string test;
  public string TestMethodCode 
  {
    get { return test; }
    set
    {
      test = value;
      if (test != null)
        test = test.Replace(" ", "");
    } 
  }
}
```